# How to return all lines of a string except first using regex, or return all text after the first number?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
Number: 2
blah one
blah two
blah three
```

I want the end result to be :

```
blah one
blah two
blah three
```

How can I achieve this using regex? What pattern do I use?

**Just an Update** : I know this can be achieved by C# implementations which does not use RegEx. But i have a limitation of using regex since this is for an internal software in which this will be run as a script. I can use grp1 = Regex.Match(,).Groups and access it using grp1[0].Value

Comment: come on, regex itself will be unhappy if you use it to do this kind of thing

Comment: What have you tried? Better yet, whats wrong with `string.Replace("Number: 2", "");`?

Comment: I have a limitation of using an internal software which has only implementation of Regex within. I can use grp1 = Regex.Match(<string>,<pattern>).Groups and access it using grp1[0].Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your new specifications, this is what worked for me:

```
string input = "Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three";
string patern = @"(?ms)^(?!Number: \d+$).*";

GroupCollection grps = Regex.Match(input, patern).Groups;
```

Now `grps[0].Value` contains `blah one\nblah two\nblah three`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if the number could change? It could be Number: 3 or Number: 4. Then what would be the pattern?

Comment: Change the number in the patern to \d+, this will match it to any number, disregarding the length.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex to match all the lines except the one that starts with `Number`

```
^(?!Number).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8eK5/2)

**Update:**

If you input string contains this characters `Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three` then you could use the below regex to match all the words except `Number 2`

```
(?<=\\n)([^\\]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8eK5/3)

Comment: Its the right idea, but a string doesn't have "lines"

Comment: but it contains newline characters.

Comment: and that would fail to find a match. `Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three`

Comment: even after using a verbatim string, i'm getting blank values in Regex.Match(string,patter).Groups for this pattern

Comment: now see my regex enclosed within paranthesis to capture the words. `([^\\]*)`

Comment: @Alfan did you try my modified pattern?

Comment: No Avinash. It still returns no value for me. 
`code`
            string str = "Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three";
            string pattern = @"(?<=\\n)[^\\]*";

            GroupCollection grpColl = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups;

            string k = grpColl[0].Value;
`code`

Comment: pattern should be, `@"(?<=\\n)([^\\]*)"` finally print the group 1.

Comment: @Alfan could you paste your code in ideone and post back the link here?

Comment: http://ideone.com/pkbXQt

    btw Avinash, i got the answer from @CDirkx
Would like to know why your pattern didn't work though..

Answer (score 1):

```
   string abc = @"Number: 2
 blah one
 blah two
blah three".Trim();

    try
    {
        Regex RegexObj = new Regex("^.*?\\n(?<data>(.|\\n)*)");
        TextBox1.Text = RegexObj.Match(abc).Groups["data"].Value;

    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {

        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
```

Comment: This pattern is not working for me. I'm getting no values while doing Regex.Match(string,pattern).Groups and putting it into a GroupCollection

Comment: I tried imolementing this in c# and i am still getting blank for ResultString: 
`code' string SubjectString = "Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three";
            string ResultString = null;
            try
            {
                Regex RegexObj = new Regex("^.*?\\r\\n(?<data>(.|\\r\\n)*)");
                ResultString = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString).Groups["data"].Value;

            }`code`

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I already got the answer from @CDirkx though.

Comment: Careful! My regex will completely ignore the first line whether it contains Number or not

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a string consisting of multiple lines meaning that it could be written as `"Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three"`, (`\n` is the newline character). You can than use the newline character as a regular character in your string manipulation. This gives you a lot of options to achieve your goal and I will list the simplest two:

1. convert your string into an array, wherein each element is a line.

   ```
   string input = "Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three";
   string[] lines = input.Split('\n');
   ```

   You can than select which lines to use in your program.
2. Get a substring containing everything but the number.

   ```
   string input = "Number: 2\nblah one\nblah two\nblah three";
   string inputWithoutNumber = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('\n') + 1);
   ```

   and use the new string in the rest of your program.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Only thing I would add is split or get the index using `Environment.NewLine` instead

Comment: Thanks, but i have a limitation of using only Regex. Because this is to be put inside like a script in an internal software. I can use grp1 = Regex.Match(<string>,<pattern>).Groups and access it using grp1[0].Value